# System.Net.HttpClient and cURL does not give identical results

Tags: c#, php, json, curl

I have an issue i don't understand.

My index.php is returning another page in JSON everytime i POST some variables, else it returns the generic page.

Basically, it works as intended with the following command:

```
curl --data "menu=mychoice&group=mygroup" http://localhost/index.php
```

returns the correct JSON object (and the generic index.php page if mychoice or mygroup is not valid)

I tryed to implement this behaviour in C# but i can't succeed in retrieving the JSON object if menu and group are correct. Here is my code:

```
    private async void WebQuery()
    {
         var client = new HttpClient();
         var url = @"http://localhost/index.php";

// not working
         var data = "menu=mymenu&group=mygroup";
         StringContent queryString = new StringContent(data);
         HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, queryString);

// or, not working too                 
        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("menu", "mymenu"));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("group", "mygroup"));
        HttpContent queryContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, queryContent);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

I'm either choosing HttpContent as StringContent or FormUrlEncodedContent, it does not work.

My index.php looks like:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['menu') && isset($_POST['group']))
{
echo json_encode(myarray);
exit;
}
header('Location: generic.php');
?>
```

I can't understand why it is working with curl and not with httpClient. Any hint, please ?

Precision: if i replace POST by GET, it works as intended with HttpClient.

Comment: Take wireshark and/or tcpdump and capture the exact http requests sent by both. Then compare

Comment: effectively the packets are differents. I'll dig this deeper, but curl ones are larger. I'll feedback this post as soon as i have figured what. Thank you, @zerkms